# How can I find out if os.popen is running the linux command in same shell?

Tags: python, linux, shell, environment-variables, popen

I've the below python function that I use to run the linux command. I'm running a script which creates some environment variable and then I'm porting all those variable into on script again by running the linux command using the function below; however it seems that the environment variables of the first command is not getting recorded using second command. I was wondering is it because the `os.popen` runs command in different shell every time I call it? If so how can I modify my code or which function to use to have everything running in the same shell?

```
def execute(cmd):
    '''Module to execute linux command'''
    try:
        proc = os.popen(cmd)
        out = proc.read().strip()
        return out
    except Exception,err:
        print "Exception occurred : %s"%str(err)
        raise(str(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.popen()` is deprecated.  In its place we have `subprocess.Popen()` and perhaps even better for your use case, `subprocess.check_output()`.  These new methods take an optional `env` argument which is a dict of environment variable names and values.  You can pass anything you need in there.

Or, if you really want to set the variables outside and have them "stick" in subprocesses, you can `export` them in the shell (`export myvarname`) before running Python.

Comment: actually I'm setting many env variable during the program and then depending on the situation only need to source back. Is there any way by which I can retain the shell itself ?

Comment: What is "the shell itself?"  The one where Python was launched from?  I'm not clear on what the workflow is.

Comment: Ok. Here is the flow of my program.

Comment: Ok. Here is the flow of my program. My python script is calling a utility(test.sh) which records the shell environment to a file.   Before calling this utility I sourced another file which had some set of shell variables.  Now when I record the environment using test.sh I don't find the shell variables that I sourced from the other file.

Comment: When you say "I source another file" what does that mean?  You mean you sourced another file from Python by launching a shell?  This will never work.  I think you might better simply "parse" the other file in Python and pass the needed variables using the `env` argument I suggested.

Comment: by source I mean that I run a linux command "source test_env". test_env contains the "setenv command for env variable", for eg " setenv DIR_run /u/rajput/qa-fo/"

Comment: I ran source test_env from python. which internally calls setenv DIR_run /u/rajput/qa-fo

Comment: Right so let me explain why this will never work.  When you run `test_env` from Python, it forks a new process which receives a copy of the environment that Python had.  `test_env` then modifies the copy of the environment, and when it exits, Python's environment remains unchanged.  To fix this, you need to change your paradigm, e.g. to have Python read the lines of `test_env` and in Python directly set `os.environ[KEY] = VALUE` for each line in `test_env`.  That will update the Python process environment.  Or you can `source test_env` in the shell *before* running your Python script.

Answer (score 0):

[popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (and in Python [os.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen)) never runs the *same* shell, but forks a new one.